# Editing the data in a List in a Dashcode app

Tags: dashcode

I’m writing a Dashcode app that contains a list. I’d like to populate this list with my data, but when I define the function

```
function populate_list()
{
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    list.setDataArray(test_data);
    list.reloadData();
}
```

I get an error; I think the reason is that `list` in this context is a normal HTML `ul` element and not an instance of the fancy `DC.List` class that Apple has defined. How can I access my list in such a way that I can use its methods and access its properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I wanted to do

`var list = document.getElementById("list").object;`

Answer (score 0):

In dashcode under library/code there is an example titled 'List Data Source'. You will also need to alter the list object datatype to dynamic and then select your datasource from the dropdown list.